# What does されています here?　レポートには間違っていた箇所が指摘されています

Tags: grammar, meaning, verbs, syntax, sentence

in this sentence (レポートには間違っていた箇所が指摘されています)

"Xが指摘されています" can mean: "X will be pointed out" or only "X is pointed out"?
"されています" can be used to express actions that will happen?

I asked it because in the original text レポートには間違っていた箇所が指摘されています it's translated as "the report will point out your mistakes".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't say 〜されている can be used to express a future action, but it can be used for a future state.

The report will be given at some time in the future and mistakes will be in a certain state on it. That the report will be given in the future must have been conveyed before this sentence.

Comment: the sentence before it's "チューターに添削してもらうと、レポートが送られてきます". then this tentense is necessary to convey the meaning of sencond sentence? Is it correct to say "Xが指摘されています" can mean: "X will be pointed out" because ている linked in される? without the sentence before it cannot mean "X will be pointed out"?

Comment: @Eagle377host - きます in the first sentence could be referring to either something that regularly happens or something that will happen at a particular time in the future. Which is more likely depends on context. されています in the second sentence describes a state (because of います). It has nothing to do with it being passive (される). The sentence says nothing about when except we know it’s not the past. The reference point of time is determined by the context.